# Inserting a INT value into a vector location?

Tags: c++, vector

First of all, I am new to C++. I am trying to figure out how to insert an Int value into a certain position in a vector.

I read online that you can use the insert function to push a value in a vector but i keep getting an overload operator error from my compiler. Do I need to make a pointer?

Here is the overall goal/assignment so that you can understand the big picture:

Build two grids which are each X wide and Y long where X and Y are user inputs to determine the size of the grids.  Fill each cell of both the grids with a ‘0’.

Randomly fill 1/3rd of the grid’s cells with a ‘1’.  You must randomly fill each of the two grids separately so they do not have all of the same squares filled with a ‘1’.

Compare the two grids (square by square comparison) to find squares which have a ‘1’ in both grids.  Create a third grid which contains a ‘1’ in squares where both the compared grids contain a ‘1’ and has a ‘0’ in any other square.

Full Source Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iterator> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

void print_vector(vector<vector<int>>& m_vec)
{
    for(auto itY : m_vec)
    {
        for(auto itX : itY)
            cout << itX << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void populate_vectors()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    //int i = 0;
    cout << "Grid Size:";
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    int fill = (x*y) / 3;

    //Vector 1
    vector<vector <int>> yVector1;
    for(auto i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    {
        vector<int> xVector1;
        for(auto j = 0; j < y; ++j)
            xVector1.push_back(0);
        yVector1.push_back(xVector1);
    }
    cout << "Vector 1:" << endl;
    print_vector(yVector1);

    //Vector 2
    vector<vector <int>> yVector2;
    for(auto i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    {
        vector<int> xVector2;
        for(auto j = 0; j < y; ++j)
            xVector2.push_back(0);
        yVector2.push_back(xVector2);
    }
    cout << "Vector 2:" << endl;
    print_vector(yVector2);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "New Vec:" << endl;
    //yVector1.insert(yVector1.begin() + x, 2); //? What I have tried
    print_vector(yVector1);
    print_vector(yVector2);
}

int main()
{
    int k; //Temporary will be removed
    populate_vectors();
    //populate_vectors();
    //populate_vectors();
    //populate_vectors();
    cin >> k; //Temporary will be removed
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `my_vector.insert(my_vector.begin() + my_index, my_value);` will insert `my_value` and shift all following elements over 1 position. Otherwise, `my_vector[my_index] = my_value;` will overwrite that position.

Comment: You can't really "insert" into an array. What you do is overwrite something that is already there. You can do the same with a vector.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to insert `2` into a vector that contains `vector<int>`. It's very unclear why you're trying to do that.

Comment: Do you mean insert or replace-in array we have no operation to insert, but we're let replace using operator[]? Insert comes with the shifting, while the replacement does not. The vector you're using has operator [] returning another vector which again has operator[] returning int.

Comment: Completely beside the point: you should write a function that creates one vector and call it twice, passing the size parameters to it. Keep all user interaction in `main`.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.